# is there any way to write conditional statements cleaner if/else

Tags: ruby

I have an if-else-statement that I would like to make more DRY.

```
if flag?
  box? && ball?
else
  box?
end
```

And maybe I have another statement that looks like this

```
if flag?
  box? && ball? 
else
  box? && ball? && bat? 
end
```

How to clean up those conditions and make them look more DRY?

Comment: _"make them look more DRY"_ –  another aspect is readability. To me, your current code is very easy to understand.

Comment: That's not DRY. The DRY principle is stated as _"Every piece of knowledge must have a single, unambiguous, authoritative representation within a system"_. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Comment: I too prefer the constructs as written to the artificial use of "and"s and "or"s. Moreover, since each method is evaluated at most once, and only when necessary, what is !DRY about the present construct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To simplify conditions like these, it sometimes helps to write them verbose and then transform them step by step, following the [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

```
if flag?
  box? && ball?
else
  box?
end
```

can be written as

```
(flag? && box? && ball?) || (!flag? && box?)
```

Because `box?` must be `true` in both cases, you can check first before the other conditions.

```
box? && ((flag? && ball?) || (!flag?))
```

Which can be transformed to

```
box? && (!flag? || ball?)
```

The other expression can be transformed, following the same steps:

```
if flag?
  box? && ball? 
else
  box? && ball? && bat? 
end
```

Write as verbose condition

```
(flag? && box? && ball?) || (!flag? && box? && ball? && bat?)
```

and transform

```
(box? && ball?) && ((flag?) || (!flag? && bat?))
```

ending up with

```
box? && ball? && (flag? || bat?)
```

Comment: I suggest `box? && (!flag? || ball?)` rather than `box? && (ball? || !flag?)` because executing the method `ball?` when `flag?` is `false` may raise an exception or have undesired side-effects, unlike the evaluation of `flag?`.  `ball?` may also be more costly to evaluate than `flag?`.

Comment: De Morgan's Laws are not directly applicable when some tokens are methods because the laws assume all tokens are known (or can be determined), yet some of the methods may depend on other tokens having certain logical values.